# Squash two commits that aren't sequential

Tags: git

I committed some code, made some changes, then committed again. I then did a git status and realized I forgot to add a file into my first commit. My log looks like:

```
commit c411e24a9af7599c5021473eff029939f80908ef
Date:   Sat Jul 9 03:34:47 2016 -0700

    Add a reducer to track load and rendered state

commit c8050c8ec1f7c889b67fabdcd2d6ae1d34017bd2
Date:   Sat Jul 9 03:32:57 2016 -0700

    Do some other stuff

commit 69d719acb16bb21c37eb9ab965801f9295f1e3a3
Date:   Sat Jul 9 03:31:52 2016 -0700

    Add a reducer to track load and rendered state
```

Where `c411e24a9af7599c5021473eff029939f80908ef` is the commit I added the file I meant to add in `69d719acb16bb21c37eb9ab965801f9295f1e3a3`.

Is there a way to, in fake code: `git squash c411e24 69d719a` where it merges those two commits together?

Answer (score 4):

You can use interactive rebase command: `git rebase -i` to change order and squash commits. Just run:

```
git rebase -i 69d719~
```

It will open a text file where you can select a new order of these three commits and decide which commits to squash. You can reorder commits from order `c411e2`, `c8050c`, `69d719` to `c8050c`, `c411e2`, `69d719`  and squash `69d719` and `c411e2`, all with one git command.